# django "<User: user556>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to save a M2M object ( set it to a default value which is the one with id = 1 ).

The problem I'm getting the following error:

> "<User: user556>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

I looked at previous feeds that covered the same error but no one explained when it happens in the form_valid function as it happened to me

My code is as follows :

```
  def form_valid(self,form):

    instance = form.instance
    instance.groups.set(1)
    instance.save()
    return super(UserCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: you must put the `instance.save()` line over the `instance.groups.set(1)` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to *save* your instance, such that it has a primary key, otherwise you can not create a record in the junction table.

You thus implement this with:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

    def form_valid(self,form):
        instance = form.save()
        instance.groups.set(1)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

returning a `HttpResponseRedirect` is necessary here since a `super().form_valid()` will save the form again to the database, and will also set the `groups` to the ones specified in the form.

Comment: There is a somewhat hacky way to call `super().form_valid()` if you want (Saw this on someone else's answer). Goes something like `response = super().form_valid()    # your code     return response`

Comment: Hi thanks the object is being saved now but the group field has not been set it's empty, maybe the problem is with the set method ?

Comment: @nassim: are you sure there is a group with `id=1`? What if you print `print(instance.groups.all())`. Furthermore as discussed, you need to remove the `super().form_valid()` call.

Comment: Thanks I resolved it the problem is that I use custom groups and calling instance.groups calls the default django group so I had to change it to instance.appname_groups ( the field name as it is in the database ) and it worked